# How do I assemble pieces of HTML into a DOMDocument?

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

It appears that `loadHTML` and `loadHTMLFile` for a files representing sections of an HTML document seem to fill in `html` and `body` tags for each section, as revealed when I output with the following:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($file);
$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('*');

if( !is_null($elements) ) {
    foreach( $elements as $element ) {
        echo "<br/>". $element->nodeName. ": ";

        $nodes = $element->childNodes;
        foreach( $nodes as $node ) {
            echo $node->nodeValue. "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Since I plan to assemble these parts into the larger document within my own code, and I've been instructed to use DOMDocument to do it, what can I do to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest you can get is to use the [`DOMDocumentFragment`](http://php.net/DOMDocumentFragment).

Then you can do:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
...
$f = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
$f->appendXML("<foo>text</foo><bar>text2</bar>"); 
$someElement->appendChild($f);
```

However, this expects XML, not HTML.

In any case, I think you're creating an artificial problem. Since you know the behavior is to create the `html` and `body` tags you can just extract the elements in the file from within the body tag and then import the, to the DOMDocument where you're assembling the final file. See [`DOMDocument::importNode`](http://pt2.php.net/DOMDocument.importNode).

Answer (score 1):

This is part of several modifications the [HTML parser module of libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-HTMLparser.html) makes to the document in order to work with broken HTML. It only occurs when using `loadHTML` and `loadHTMLFile` on partial markup. If you know the partial is valid X(HT)ML, use `load` and `loadXML` instead.

You could use

```
$doc->saveXml($doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0));
```

to dump the outerHTML of the body element, e.g. `<body>anything else</body>` and strip the body element with `str_replace` or extract the inner html with `substr`.

```
$html = '<p>I am a fragment</p>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html); // added html and body tags
echo substr(
    $dom->saveXml(
        $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)
    ),
    6, -7
);
// <p>I am a fragment</p>
```

Note that this will use XHTML compliant markup, so `<br>` would become `<br/>`. As of PHP 5.3.5, there is no way to pass a node to `saveHTML()`. [A bug request has been filed.](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39771)

Comment: Is saving to XML and reloading efficient?

Comment: @Hamster in what regard or compared to what? I'd assume i/o performance to be the same as for any other file operation. What takes time is the (de-)serialization from/to DOM instances. If you have any concerns about performance consider running a benchmark.