# Is this the best way to import the body of an (HTML) DOMDocument into another?

Tags: php, html, dom, import, html-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to insert HTML to PHP DOMNode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400980/how-to-insert-html-to-php-domnode)

Continuing off of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726969/how-do-i-assemble-pieces-of-html-into-a-domdocument), here's the code I'm about to start using:

```
function getHTMLDOMSegment( $file )
{
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTMLFile( $file );
    $body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
    return $body->childNodes;
}
```

Then I'd simply iterate over the children, using [importNode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php) and append each wherever they need to go in another HTML-loaded DOMDocument.

Does this sound right?

**Edit:** To be clear, since the source files I'm working with may not be "proper" XHTML, I need to go through loadHTMLFile like this no matter what, apparently.

Also, because this might be having to work with a large amount of HTML content, my goal is to be efficient as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am somewhat reluctant to answer this question because it is basically just a longer version of what Artefacto and I already told you, but anyway.

You can either add the raw XML subtree and add it through a fragment

- [`DOMDocumentFragment::appendXML` — Append raw XML data](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocumentfragment.appendxml.php)

Or use

- [`DOMDocument::importNode` — Import node into current document](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php)

Note that you can deep import entire trees by passing `TRUE` as the second argument.

**Examples:**

```
$a = <<< HTML
<div>
    <h2>Hello World</h2>
    <p> I am from the <abbr title="source">src</abbr> document<br/></p>
</div>
HTML;

$b = <<< HTML
<h1>Importing Fragments</h1>
HTML;
```

**Using fragments:**

```
$dest = new DOMDocument;
$dest->loadHTML($b);
$fragment = $dest->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXML($a);
$dest->getElementsByTagName('h1')->item(0)->appendChild($fragment);
echo $dest->saveHTML();
```

**Using imports:**

```
$dest = new DOMDocument;
$dest->loadHTML($b);
$src = new DOMDocument;
$src->loadHTML($a);
$dest->getElementsByTagName('h1')->item(0)->appendChild(
    $dest->importNode(
        $src->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0),
        TRUE
    )
);
echo $dest->saveHTML();
```

The output for both of these would be something like

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC 
    "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">

<html><body><h1>Importing Fragments<div>
    <h2>Hello World</h2>
    <p> I am from the <abbr title="source">src</abbr> document<br></p>
</div></h1></body></html>
```

If you are concerned about which one performs better, I suggest to benchmark these under real world conditions, e.g. in your application. Then judge for yourself which suits your needs.

Comment: Serializing to a string and then back into a DOM data structure seems like it might be inefficient, though.  At least, that's how I understand what appendXML does from its description...

Comment: Also, by subtree you mean the descendants of the each of the body's immediate child elements?

Comment: @Hamster You didnt answer what you consider efficient in the last question already. Until you clarify that or give a benchmark I'd say it doesnt make a difference. By subtree I mean the entire node. In your specific UseCase it means you would indeed have to iterate if you dont want to add XML including the body.

Comment: Efficient in terms of CPU and memory use, I'm guessing.  I could be dealing with a lot of HTML content here, potentially.

Comment: @Hamster Well, like I said. If you have any doubts, benchmark. I dont know if one performs better than the other. I've never noticed a significant overall impact on applications where I  am using them.